# Dash, save input as a variable

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have a code on Jupyter that works like this:

```
You input a keyword
The code makes a couple of API calls based on the keyword
The code merges and wrangles the optained databases
The code plots with Plotly
```

Now, I'd like to put this code online for my colleagues, but I never used Dash. The user should only:

```
Use an input box
Press confirm
Obtain the graphs
```

I need to save the input as a variable, but how to do this? I'm following this example:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div([
dcc.Input(id='my-id', value='initial value', type='text'),
html.Div(id='my-div')
])


@app.callback(
Output(component_id='my-div', component_property='children'),
[Input(component_id='my-id', component_property='value')]
)
def update_output_div(input_value):
return 'You\'ve entered "{}"'.format(input_value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Is it possible save the value from the box as a python variable? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Certainly. You can change the callback function like this:

```py
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='my-div', component_property='children'),
    [Input(component_id='my-id', component_property='value')]
)
def update_output_div(input_value):
    my_variable = input_value
    return 'You\'ve entered "{}"'.format(my_variable)
```

Give it whichever name you like, and use it from there like any Python variable.

Edit:
Perhaps I should mention that the arg, `input_value` is already a Python variable, which you can already use just like you would any other.